# Followup to Gradle 1.3: build.gradle not building classes

Tags: java, spring, build.gradle

I am actually using the newly released Gradle 2, but having the same issues as described in the previous post.

I am also a newb trying to follow the example given in the Spring guide (http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/#scratch) but after my first compile, there were no classes.

I have tried various configurations of tree structure including adding the structure and code suggested in the above thread:

"I guess the source file path is src/org/gradle/example/simple/HelloWorld.java. (The diagram shows something different.) That doesn't match Gradle's default, so you'll have to reconfigure it: sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src"] –  Peter Niederwieser Dec 7 '12 at 1:23 "

adding the line: sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src"]  allows the code to compile, however, I still have no classes.

Here is the successful build.

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.468 secs
```

Here is the build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs=["src"]

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
 }

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-gradle'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

task wrapper(type:Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'
```

Where are my classes? Please help.

Comment: continuing to debug, I noticed that the gradleVersion was wrong (typed brainlessly in from the example text).  Fixed that, but it still does not work.  Still no classes.

Comment: Were you able to fix this ? I hit the same issue and was curious if you were able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I got stuck with the same problem, I hacked around for a bit before I understood the reason for this behavior.
My project structure was like so

```
MyProject
  - src
    - main
      - java
        - hello
          HelloWorld.java
          build.gradle
```

The problem was that the build.gradle is *supposed to be under the Project-Root folder* i.e. **MyProject** and not under the **hello** folder !!!

Changed it so that my Project structure looks like below, ran the gradle build and saw that classes folder was created:

```
MyProject
  - src
    - main
      - java
        - hello
          HelloWorld.java
build.gradle
```

When you think about it, the build.gradle is used to build the complete project and not just the classes within one folder and should rightfully sit under the project-root folder.